# MAC address in arp table doesn't match actual MAC, why?

Tags: mac, arp, ubiquiti

If I connect my laptop directly to the config port of a ubnt airFiber radio I can set a static IP to my laptop and access the default config page to change settings on the radio.

When I look at the arp table on my windows laptop the MAC for the radio's IP is 02-27-22-da-87-c2, but this is wrong. The actual MAC is 00-27-22-da-87-c2.

How can the OUI be off like that in my arp table yet I'm still able to access the radio config?

Comment: What? You've listed the same MAC address.

Comment: The first octet has a 2 instead of a 0, they're not the same. The OUI is different.